# When does a מעריב-misser say תחנון?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, shacharis-morning-prayer, tachanun

קצור שלחן ערוך‎ 21:1 describes what one should do who missed מעריב by accident:

> לאחר תפילת שחרית יאמר תחנון ואשרי ויתפלל תפלת שמונה עשרה לשם ערבית ואחר כך יאמר למנצח ובא לציון וכו׳
>
> After the prayer of שחרית, he should say תחנון and אשרי and then say שמונה עשרה for מעריב. After that, he should say למנצח,‎ ובא לציון, etc.

When should he do this? Specifically: Is the intent that this person say תחנון and אשרי with the congregation, or immediately after his own שמונה עשרה?

Answer (score 3):

See *Mishna B'rura* ([108](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%97):11), who indicates that the repetition of the *amida* does not create a problematic interruption since the person is still involved in the first prayer. Thus, it appears that the person should wait and say *tachanun* and *ashrei* with the congregation.

Comment: On days with Torah reading, another question would be whether the person should go straight from *tachanun* to *ashrei* to the *tashlumin*, skipping the Torah reading.

Comment: He should probably say tachanun after both Amida's, tachanun being essentially a part of shemoneh esrei and the custom to omit tachanun at night no longer applying (in accordance with the general rule of treating a tashlumin prayer in accordance with the laws of the current time).